# Alternative ways to see inverse of block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we had a $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$ consisting of blocks $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{0}$, $\mathbf{*}$, and $\mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{A}$ is $k \times k$ and invertible, $*$ is arbitrary, and the identity $\mathbf{I}$ is $n-k \times n-k$.

$\mathbf{M} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{A} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{*} & \mathbf{I} \end{bmatrix}$

I am told this matrix is invertible. Can someone help me see this?

One way I thought about it was as follows:
I can see that the identity has $n-k$ eigenvalues equalling 1. I can see that $A$ has $k$ non-zero eigenvalues. But I don't see the theorem as to why I can say that M has $n$ non-zero eigenvalues.

Comment: Another way to see that is to do row reduction on the first $k$ rows. That does not affect the part with matrix $I$.

Comment: Ah yes... don't know why I did not think of that. But is there a way to continue along my eigenvalue train of thought?

Comment: Absolutely! The other $k$ eigenvalues of $M$ are precisely $k$ eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @mathmath Can you remind me of the theorem which gives you this conclusion?

Comment: One way is to compute the characteristic polynomial of $M$. It will be the product of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and characteristic polynomial of $I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write what the inverse would be: you need
$$
\begin{bmatrix} A&0\\ B&I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} X&Y\\ Z&W\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} I&0\\ 0&I\end{bmatrix}.
$$
This gives you the four equalities
$$
AX=I,\qquad AY=0,\qquad BX+Z=0,\qquad BY+W=I.
$$
The first equation gives us that $X=A^{-1}$. Then the second equation gives you $Y=0$. The third one is $Z=-BA^{-1}$, and the fourth one is now $W=I$. So the inverse is
$$\begin{bmatrix} A^{-1}&0\\ -BA^{-1}&I\end{bmatrix}.$$You can easily check that this is also the left inverse (or use that for matrices invertibility on one side is enough).